# How to pre-fill Form in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, init

i am currently working with `Forms` in `SwiftUI`. I am implementing a **EditUser View** and therefore am trying to **pre-fill the Form** with the previous Inputs

> I am passing a **User Object** which contains all the relevant Data and using the **initializer** to update all of the input states.

```swift
struct EditUserView: View {
    
    let user: User?
    @Binding var showEditUserView: Bool
    
    @State private var gender: User.Gender = .notSet
    @State private var firstName: String = ""
    @State private var lastName: String = ""
    
    init(for user: User?, show: Binding<Bool>) {
        // First, update the Struct Properties with the given Values
        self.user = user
        self._showEditUserView = show
        
        // Second, if a User was given, update all Inputs with the given Values
        if let safeUser = user {
            gender = safeDoctor.gender
            firstName = safeDoctor.firstName
            lastName = safeDoctor.lastName
        }
    }

    // Some other Code

    Picker(selection: $gender, label: Text("Gender")) {
        ForEach(User.Gender.allCases, id: \.self) { gender in
            if gender != .notSet { Text(gender.string).tag(gender) }
        }
    }
    HStack {
        TextField("FirstName", text: $firstName)
        Divider()
        TextField("LastName", text: $lastName)
    }
```

> When creating a new instance of EditUserView while providing a User (NOT nil), the input fields are not getting updated with the provided values.

**Can anyone spot a reason for this not to be working?**

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you sure you are actually providing values to update? Honestly, you would be better off making `User` an ObservableObject that you can bind to your TextFields directly. I suspect that your unwrapping is failing, and `firstName` and `lastName` are defaulting to an empty string, which is an actual value, and that is what you textfields are showing. Did you set breakpoints to check the values at the various places?

Comment: why `safeUser` becomes `safeDoctor`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

States should be initialized differently - not by value, but as `State`.

Here is fixed variant:

```
struct EditUserView: View {
    
    let user: User?
    @Binding var showEditUserView: Bool
    
    @State private var gender: User.Gender    // here declare only
    @State private var firstName: String
    @State private var lastName: String
    
    init(for user: User?, show: Binding<Bool>) {
        // First, update the Struct Properties with the given Values
        self.user = user
        self._showEditUserView = show
        
        // Second, if a User was given, update all Inputs with the given Values
        self._gender = State(initialValue: user.gender ?? .notSet)
        self._firstName = State(initialValue: user.firstName ?? "")
        self._lastName = State(initialValue: user.lastName ?? "")
    }

    // ... other code
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your code that sets your `@State` variables in an `.onAppear()` modifier for your `EditUserView` instead of the initializer. That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

In functional programming , we can track the changes in Struct, so that using Struct as model ( User ) is the best way.

then you can use like below.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var user: User
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("FirstName", text: $user.firstName)
            Divider()
            TextField("LastName", text: $user.lastName)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(user: User(firstName: "christophriepe", lastName: "last name"))
    }
}

struct User {
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. This is unluckily not possible since Doctor is an Optional and may be nil